# Sed not replacing every occurrence of dot and forward slash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've got `$dir` which holds a string like `./Account/` where the word 'Account' can be any word (e.g. App, Home, etc).

I want to get rid of the `.` and both occurrences of `/` to wind up with just `Account`. Here's the pattern I'm using: `sed 's/\.\///g'`.

This is the string I'm applying it on:

```
"import React from 'react';

const $(echo $dir | sed 's/\.\///g') = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>App</h1>
  </div>
);

export default App;"
```

The `.` and first `/` is removed from the output but it still has the second occurrence of the `/`.

Output:

```
import React from 'react';

const Account/ = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>App</h1>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

How can I make it so that even the second `/` is removed?

Comment: Just to add, the `/g` flag should remove every occurrence in theory, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/\.\///g'
```

That removes every `./`, not every `.` and `/`.

You want

```
sed 's|[/.]||g'
```

Using `|` instead of `/` as delimiter is a good idea to avoid the need to escape `/`.

Example:

```
$ sed 's|[/.]||g' <<< './Account/'
Account
```

Comment: This was my first shell script and first time using sed. Your answer was precise and the explanation, very easy to follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$(echo $dir | sed 's,\./\([^/]*\)/,\1,g')
```

The regex delimiters are changed to `,` so as not to have to escape slashes.

**Details**

- `\./` - `./` substring
- `\([^/]*\)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1` placeholder from RHS): any 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `/` -  a `/` char.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for the string `./`, whereas you want to be searching for either a `.` or a `/`.

Replace the search string with the character class `[\/.]` like so:

```
echo "./Account/" | sed 's/[\/.]//g'
```

output:

```
Account
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two substitutions to remove `./` from the beginning and `/` from the end of `$dir`.

```
echo "$dir" | sed 's|^\./||; s|/$||'
```